# Dots in bootstrap and css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I dont know how to make dots in css
(look at image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXrD0.png)

```
</br> . </br> . </br> ....
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.  Do you want it to look exactly like the picture?  Do you actually need to do it with Bootstrap?

Comment: yes but i cant i try make . </br> . </br> etc.

Comment: Use <ul><li>...</li></ul> etc; and set background color, radius, and / or image.

Answer (score 4):

That's neither a case for Bootstrap nor for CSS or even HTML. What you need is SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 6 42" width="6px" height="42px">
  <circle cx="3" cy="3" r="3" fill="white" fill-opacity="1.0"/>
  <circle cx="3" cy="15" r="3" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.8333"/>
  <circle cx="3" cy="27" r="3" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.6667"/>
  <circle cx="3" cy="39" r="3" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

You can embed it via an `<img>` element or paste it directly in place of the `<br>`s and dots.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of ways you could accomplish this, but those dots just look like `li` bullets, so creating a list with empty `li`s might be the easiest way. You can achieve the fading effect using `opacity`.

```css
li:nth-child(1) {
  opacity:1;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  opacity:.75;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  opacity:.5;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  opacity:.25;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Clever but seems kind of hacky

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still not sure exactly what you want and what your requirements are, but take a look at this and see if it helps:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}
 

.dot {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: .25em;
}

.dot.one { color: #000 }
.dot.two { color: #555 }
.dot.three { color: #999 }
.dot.four { color: #CCC }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="dot one">.</div>
<div class="dot two">.</div>
<div class="dot three">.</div>
<div class="dot four">.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean with CSS like this? https://jsfiddle.net/t9hmxz0z/

HTML (far from beautiful, but it gets the job done)

```
<div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width: 8px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

span {
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #888;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #666;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #444;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #222;
}

span {
  last-child: margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS Only...

A little "hacky", but I thought I'd have some fun with this one.

https://jsfiddle.net/etmargallo/vvn5zxn1/5/

HTML:

```
<div>
   <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  border-left: 5px dotted white;
}

div > span {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -5px;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-size: cover;
}
```